# Try to remove the first duplicated value but remove more instead

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I'm trying to remove the first occurrence of some duplicated values in my dataframe, but I'm pretty sure that my code is dropping more values.

```
data=
columns>> A - Value
       >> 1 - 3
          2 - 3 
          3 - 2
          4 - 2
          5 - 2 
          6 - 4
          7 - 4
          ...
mask = data[data.duplicated(data.columns[data.columns.isin(['A'])],keep='first')==True].index 
ajustes3 = data.drop(mask)


print(mask)
Int64Index([  0,   2,  5,  6,  7, ...4318, 4352, 4353, 4354, 4355, 4471, 4472, 4473, 4474, 4475],dtype='int64', length=1165)
```

Sorry if the question is not clear. What I am missing? how to improve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[3,3,2,2,2,4,4]})

df.loc[df.groupby('A').cumcount()>0]
```

Output

```
   A
1  3
3  2
4  2
6  4
```